# compiling typescript into javascript code

Tags: javascript, typescript, compilation

this is a compiled enum from typescript to javascript. i really enjoy seeing the compiled javascript version to learn more javascript stuff. i came across with a really complex code for defining enums, could someone help me and describe this code?

its a simple question but i think its very good to understand advanced concepts in javascript

```
var Color;
(function (Color) {
  Color[Color["Red"]] = 0] = "Red";
  Color[Color["Green"]] = 1] = "Green";
  Color[Color["Blue"]] = 2] = "Blue";
})(Color || (Color = {}))
```

Comment: I believe this is the first necessary reading for you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

Comment: And this would be the second: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Comment: And here the third: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR. By the way, are you sure you copy/pasted it correctly? Those brackets don't match.

Comment: i have passed double brackes after the colors for some reason. sorry. thanks for the links, i will check out